# Saving a png image to json file in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, base64, png, jpeg

I need to save a png image to a json file in python. In addition, the beginning of the json file must look like this:

```
{"image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/etc.
```

I suspect that this means that I also need to convert it into jpeg format.

This is what I've tried this far:

```
import base64, json

filename = 'example_png.png'
f = open(filename, 'rb')
img_data = f.read()
f.close()
enc_data = base64.b64encode(img_data)

json.dump({'image':enc_data}, open('example_png.json', 'w'))
```

This resulted in the the following error:
**TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable**

I've also played around with decoding. For example, I added

```
enc_data = enc_data.decode('utf-8')
```

before saving to the json file. Then something was saved to the file, but obviously not in the right format.

I would be really grateful for any help.

Comment: Basically, you have 3 problems. 1) the error message (which you already fixed), 2) the format conversion from png to jpg and 3) the correct output string. Regarding 1) `b64encode()` returns a string, but as bytes, therefore ` .encode()` is correct and converts the result to a string. 2) the string is a base64 representation of a png image, there is no conversion happening anywhere. 3) your JSON file will look like `{"image": "iVBORw..."}` , you would need to add "data:image/jpeg;base64," in front of the Base64 string. So the remaining problem is the conversion to jpg.

Comment: If the conversion to jpg is important, refer to the linked Q/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import base64
import json

filename = "your_image.png"

with open(filename, "rb") as f_in, open("example_png.json", "w") as f_out:
    enc_data = base64.b64encode(f_in.read()).decode("utf-8")
    json.dump({"image": f"data:image/png;base64,{enc_data}"}, f_out)
```

---

EDIT: To convert the image to Jpeg and save it to Json you can use `Pillow` module:

```py
import base64
import json
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image

filename = "<your image.jpg|png>"

with open("example_png_jpeg.json", "w") as f_out:
    png_image = Image.open(filename)
    jpg_buffer = BytesIO()
    png_image.save(jpg_buffer, format="JPEG")

    enc_data = base64.b64encode(jpg_buffer.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
    json.dump({"image": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{enc_data}"}, f_out)
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've updated my anwer.

Comment: Thank you! I got an error message, but added the following lines:
    if png_image.mode != 'RGB':
        png_image = png_image.convert('RGB'), and then it worked!